# Agregar JQuery en Wordpress mediante HOOKS

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo una función que se ejecuta por medio de un hook en wordpress, en el cual instalo el JQuery

```
add_action('init', 'iniciarJQuery');
function iniciarJQuery() {
   if( !is_admin()){
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"), false, '');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
}
```

cómo saber si se puede comparar si el JQuery está instalado o no, para evitar duplicados y conflictoS

ya sé cómo utilizar als versiones locales, pero se puede comparar si en la página está instalada el jQuery antes de que yo lo instale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber si un script está en uso necesitás la función [`wp_script_is()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is).

```
if ( ! is_admin() && ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    // jQuery no está cargado
}
```